# Google Play Store not always shows current app version

Tags: android, google-play

I have a question regarding the information shown in an app section in the play store. In the "Further Information" area of an app, usually the current app version is shown. Since there is no API I have to rely on this information for a small app I intend to program.

However, I figured out that the current app version is sometimes shown, sometimes not. I wonder why this is. Is there a reason for that? I was not able to find info in this regard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

App Version on PlayStore is not shown in case it differs version according to different Android version or hardware feature(display density, processor architecture etc.) support. So multiple versions of app are live on playStore at a time and the version is not shown. When you install that app, the compatible version of app that support your device is installed.